# Embed a div table within a div table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to achieve the following layout in HTML using div tags instead of table tags (the colouring is just to make it more clear which cells I want to have equal width):

[image]

That is, I would like to be able to unfold a table layout within another table layout using only div tags. Is that possible?

Below here I have included one of my experiments. As you can see the first column is getting too wide. The inner table does not span the entire width.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffdb4d;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa64d;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #b800e6;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #66b3ff;
}
.green {
  background-color: #70db70;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell11</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell21</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell31</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell41</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell12</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell22</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell32</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell42</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell13</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell23</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell33</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell43</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some other text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell15</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell25</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell35</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell16</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell26</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell36</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It honestly makes more sense to use the actual table elements at this point.

Answer (score 2):

you should use flex for this:

```css
.table {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.cell {
  flex:1;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px gray;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
.cell.green {
  flex:3.06;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffdb4d;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa64d;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #b800e6;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #66b3ff;
}
.green {
  background-color: #70db70;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell11</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell21</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell31</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell41</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell12</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell22</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell32</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell42</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell13</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell23</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell33</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell43</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some other text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell15</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell25</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell35</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell16</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell26</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell36</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or drop display:table on parent to break the table-layout. colspan CSS is not avalaible.

```css
.table {
  display: inline-block;/* instead table to be able to shrink on content as table does*/
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:1em 0;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;/* add/remove this to find out what behavior on width it involves*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px gray
}
.cell.green {
  width:73%;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffdb4d;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa64d;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #b800e6;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #66b3ff;
}
.green {
  background-color: #70db70;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell11</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell21</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell31</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell41</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell12</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell22</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell32</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell42</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell13</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell23</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell33</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell43</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell blue">Some other text:</div>
      <div class="cell green">blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell15</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell25</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell35</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell16</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell26</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell36</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, there it is! :o Let me try it out!!

Comment: @Stine if you think the answer usefull you may upvote: it shows answer has some interest to anyone having a similar question looking for answers. If this answer solves your issue, you may also accept it.

Comment: Yup, just wanted to try it out first. I have no idea why, but it seems to work! ;D

Comment: @Stine thanks for the feed back, your try did not work cause your nested css table was standing in 1 cell only, it did not span through the 4 col of the rest of the markup. IN HTML Table, you would have set your table inside a <td colspan="4"> wich cannot be set via CSS ;)

Comment: I see :) I just noticed that the table breaks when i resize my window... but maybe that is what you try to solve in the second round of codes?

Comment: @stine second row is based on display:table. on both example, each rows behave on their own as single flex row or tables . flex:1 or table-layout:fixed is suppose to spray each cells like evenly. your nested tablelike is in the way breaking the CSS table-layout. a real html table would accept colspan and won't see its layout broken. its a CSS compromise :)

Comment: @stine i rewrote a bit your html , added a width to the table and an equal negative margin to the nested table to allow it to span through the 4 cols. (commented the 3 div / cell missing) http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/QNWgqg  here cols are not suppose to break, but explicite width is required to main container

Answer (score 1):

here is the code that you will need to accomplish what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            min-width: 200px;
            min-height: 200px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-column-group;">
            <div style="display: table-column; background-color: #FFE061;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-column; background-color: #FFC072;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-column; background-color: #FF605E;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-column; background-color: #9D44B8;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now let's explain all of this
as you requested you want to create a table but without the table html tag
you can do so with divs using CSS3 specifically using the display in order to choose how to display this div (note that the default value is block for divs)
I believe you would be able to understand it much better if you compare between the two codes the one with the divs and the other which is a normal table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            min-height: 500px;
            min-width: 600px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="background-color: #FFE061;" />
            <col style="background-color: #FFC072;" />
            <col style="background-color: #FF605E;" />
            <col style="background-color: #9D44B8;" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this solution. But it would be better using classes instead of inline coding. Inline code decreases browser performance.

Comment: Thanks, but this part I already know! It was more how to achieve a table within a table in the way I have tried to illustrate with my drawing...

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion: I don't really understand why to use div instead of tables in this case.
It seems to be a "table" for real tabular data, tables would make it easier for you.

Even though, yes! :D You can achieve this using divs and css.
I made you an example and you can see it working here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNWKdV

It would be useful for you to use css classes like `.w[size]` as you can see below.

```html
<div class="table w100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell11</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell21</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell31</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell41</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell12</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell22</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell32</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell42</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell13</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell23</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell33</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell43</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table w100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell w30 blue">Some text:</div>
    <div class="cell w70 green">blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell w30 blue">Some other text:</div>
    <div class="cell w70 green">blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table w100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell15</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell25</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell35</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell16</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell26</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell36</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  width: 25%;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffdb4d;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa64d;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #b800e6;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #66b3ff;
}
.green {
  background-color: #70db70;
}

.w5  {width:  5%;}
.w10 {width: 10%;}
.w15 {width: 15%;}
.w20 {width: 20%;}
.w25 {width: 25%;}
.w30 {width: 30%;}
.w35 {width: 35%;}
.w40 {width: 40%;}
.w45 {width: 45%;}
.w50 {width: 50%;}
.w55 {width: 55%;}
.w60 {width: 60%;}
.w65 {width: 65%;}
.w70 {width: 70%;}
.w75 {width: 75%;}
.w80 {width: 80%;}
.w85 {width: 85%;}
.w90 {width: 90%;}
.w95 {width: 95%;}
.w100 {width: 100%;}
```

I hope you can accomplish your task.

Good luck.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but to me the output of this looks similar to what I posted? The inner table only spans the first column of the main table...

Answer (score 1):

You can make the three separated tables rather than one. See the updated example:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; /*new*/
  width: 100%; /*new*/
  margin-bottom: 20px; /*new*/
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffdb4d;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa64d;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #b800e6;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #66b3ff;
}
.green {
  background-color: #70db70;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell11</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell21</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell31</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell41</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell12</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell22</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell32</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell42</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell13</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell23</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell33</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell43</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell blue" style="width:30%;">Some text:</div>
    <div class="cell green">blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell blue">Some other text:</div>
    <div class="cell green">blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell15</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell25</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell35</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell yellow">cell16</div>
    <div class="cell orange">cell26</div>
    <div class="cell red">cell36</div>
    <div class="cell purple">cell46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The single table layout is causing the inner table's width to match the width of the first column.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I ensure that e.g. all yellow cells are equal width then? Without specifying a static width...

Comment: I have that in the example, which is `table-layout:fixed;` that will do the equal width column unless yo specify a width manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a inline-block-solution using nth-child for backgrounds and borders. It has some pros and some cons:

- Very clean and readable html and no nested tables. Styles are easy to override and does not depend on things like colspan.
- The drawback that the number of divs in a row breaks the layout is admittedly pretty bad, but can be fixed by wrapping each row in a new tag - of course at the expense of more html.
- Removing classes on each row/cell is a relief, but instead the CSS readability suffers. (I do however prefer it this way!)

```css
   .table{
      width: 700px;          
      font-size: 0;
    }
    .table > div > div {
      width: 20%;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1rem;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 2px 6px;
    }

    /** Default rows */
    /*****************/
    .rows-default {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .rows-default div {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .rows-default div:nth-child(4n+1) {
      background-color: #FFE05F;
    }
    .rows-default div:nth-child(4n+2) {
      background-color: #FFC072;
    }
    .rows-default div:nth-child(4n+3) {
      background-color: #FF605E;
    }
    .rows-default div:nth-child(4n+4) {
      width: 40%;
      background-color: #9D44B8;
      border-right: none;
    }
    .rows-default div:nth-last-child(-n+4){
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    /* Highlighted rows */
    /********************/
    .rows-highlight{ 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
      margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .rows-highlight div {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .rows-highlight div:nth-child(2n+1) {
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #64B2DF;
    }
    .rows-highlight div:nth-child(2n+2) {
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #9CE25A;
      border-right: none;
    }
    .rows-highlight div:nth-last-child(-n+2){
      border-bottom: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="rows-default">
    <div>cell11</div>
    <div>cell21</div>
    <div>cell31</div>
    <div>cell41</div>

    <div>cell12</div>
    <div>cell22</div>
    <div>cell32</div>
    <div>cell42</div>

    <div>cell13</div>
    <div>cell23</div>
    <div>cell33</div>
    <div>cell43</div>
  </div>

  <div class="rows-highlight">
    <div>Some text:</div>
    <div>blah blah</div>

    <div>Some other text:</div>
    <div>blah blah blah</div>
  </div>

  <div class="rows-default">
    <div>cell11</div>
    <div>cell21</div>
    <div>cell31</div>
    <div>cell41</div>

    <div>cell12</div>
    <div>cell22</div>
    <div>cell32</div>
    <div>cell42</div>

    <div>cell13</div>
    <div>cell23</div>
    <div>cell33</div>
    <div>cell43</div>
  </div>
</div>
```